Is there a way to "rearrange" arrays when selecting?
I have a table post_likes with one column being a post ID (uint), and another column being an array of IDs (uint[]) of users who liked the post.
If I'm selecting info from multiple tables on multiple users, how do I join this post_likes table in a way that for every user, every result has an array of post IDs that user liked?
I know a one to many, or many to many storage would've made this trivial, but that's what I have to work with.

Why use the non-standard uint type? Using plain int, the extension intarray could help with performance. Also, show a query (even if it's not working) and what the result should be. And always disclose your Postgres version.

I assuming you have the following table structure:
post_likes(post_id, user_ids) where post_id is an integer and user_ids is an array of integers representing user IDs.
Approach: Flatten the Array of User IDs and aggregate Post IDs for Each User

unnest to transform the array of user IDs into a set of rows
the results by user ID and aggregate the post IDs into an array.


Heres the code :) You can remove the insertion part I put for testing purpose in my compiler
CREATE TABLE post_likes (
    post_id INT,
    user_ids INT[]
);

INSERT INTO post_likes (post_id, user_ids) VALUES
    (1, ARRAY[1, 2, 3]),
    (2, ARRAY[2, 4]),
    (3, ARRAY[1, 4, 5]),
    (4, ARRAY[3, 5]);

CREATE TABLE users (
    user_id INT,
    user_name TEXT
);

INSERT INTO users (user_id, user_name) VALUES
    (1, 'Alice'),
    (2, 'Bob'),
    (3, 'Charlie'),
    (4, 'David'),
    (5, 'Eve');

SELECT
    u.user_id,
    u.user_name,
    ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT pl.post_id) AS liked_post_ids
FROM
    users u
LEFT JOIN post_likes pl ON u.user_id = ANY(pl.user_ids)
GROUP BY
    u.user_id, u.user_name
ORDER BY
    u.user_id;


You can join with
FROM post_likes
   JOIN users
      ON ARRAY[users.id] <@ post_likes.user_ids

<@ is the "is contained in" operator for arrays. The performance won't be great.
